# Haskell: map length . group is way slower than explicit recursion?

Tags: performance, haskell, grouping, lazy-evaluation, prime-factoring

Consider this trivial algorithm of prime-decomposition of an integer `n`: Let `d'` be the divisor of `n` last found. Initially, set `d'=1`. Find the smallest divisor `d>d'` of `n`, and find the maximal value `e` such that `de` divides `n`. Append `de` to the answer and repeat the procedure on `n/de`. Finally, stop when `n` becomes 1. For simplicity, let's ignore mathematical optimizations, like stop at `sqrt n` etc.

I have implemented it in two ways. The first one generates a list of division "attempts", and then groups the successful ones by divisors. For example, for `n=20`, we first generate `[(2,20),(2,10),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(5,5),(5,1)]`, which we then transform to the desired `[(2,2),(5,1)]` using `group` and other library functions.

The second implementation is an explicit recursion which keeps track of the exponent `e` along the way, appends `de` to the answer once the maximal `e` is reached, proceeds to finding the "next" `d`, and so on.

**Question 1:** Why does the first implementation run way slower than the second, despite the following:

- Both the implementations execute `div`, the core step of the algorithm, roughly the same number of times.
- Lazy evaluation (and fusion?) has the effect that the long list illustrated above never has to be materialized in the first place. As you can see in the code below, `divTrials n`, the list I am talking about, is transformed by a chain of higher order functions. In that, I think that the part `map (\xs-> (head xs,length xs)) ... group` should tell the compiler that the list is just intermediate:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
module GroupCheck where
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

implement1 :: Integral t=> t -> [(t,Int)]                    -- IMPLEMENTATION 1
implement1  = map (\xs-> (head xs,length xs)).factorGroups where
  tryDiv (d,n)
    | n `mod` d == 0 = (d,n `div` d)
    | n == 1 = (1,1) -- hack
    | otherwise = (d+1,n)
  divTrials n = takeWhile (/=(1,1)) $ (2,n): map tryDiv (divTrials n)
  factorGroups = filter (not.null).map tail.group.map fst.divTrials

implement2 :: Show t => Integral t => t -> [(t,Int)]         -- IMPLEMENTATION 2
implement2 num = keep2 $ tail $ go (1,0,1,num) where
  range d n = [d+1..n]
  nextd d n = fromMaybe n $ find ((0==).(n`mod`)) (range d n)
  update (d,e,de,n)
    | n `mod` d == 0 = update (d,e+1,de*d,n`div`d)
    | otherwise      = (d,e,de,n)
  go (d,e,de,1) = [(d,e,de,1)]
  go (d,e,de,n) = (d,e,de,n) : go (update (nextd d n,0,1,n))
  keep2 = map (\(d,e,_,_)->(d,e))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let n = 293872
  let ans1 = implement1 n 
  let ans2 = implement2 n
  print ans1
  print ans2
```

Profiling tells us that `tryDiv` and `divTrials` together eat up >99% of the entire execution time:

```
> stack ghc -- -main-is GroupCheck.main -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts GroupCheck 
> ./GroupCheck +RTS -p >/dev/null && cat GroupCheck.prof


           GroupCheck +RTS -p -RTS

        total time  =       18.34 secs   (18338 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc = 17,561,404,568 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE          MODULE     SRC                          %time %alloc

implement1.divTrials GroupCheck GroupCheck.hs:12:3-69         52.6   69.2
implement1.tryDiv    GroupCheck GroupCheck.hs:(8,3)-(11,25)   47.2   30.8
```

**Question 1.5:** So.. what's so bad about these functions? Also,

**Question 2:** In a more general case of having to aggregate contiguous blocks of identical elements from a nondecreasing sequence, should we go the bulky `implement2` way if we want speed? (Again, ignoring domain-specific optimizations.)

Or did I totally miss something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: `divTrials` is super inefficient because every recursive call starts from scratch. You should bind the actual list in a `let` if you want to reuse it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to establish a baseline, I ran your program on a slightly larger starting number (so that `time` didn't print out 0.00s). I chose `n = 2938722345623` for no particular reason. Here's the timings before starting to tweak things:

`ans1`: indistinguishable from infinity (I finished writing this entire answer and it was still running, about 26 minutes in total)
`ans2`: 2.78s

The first thing to try is to tweak this line:

```
divTrials n = takeWhile (/=(1,1)) $ (2,n): map tryDiv (divTrials n)
```

This looks like a pretty natural definition, but it turns out that GHC never memoizes function calls. So if you want to make a list that's defined recursively in terms of itself, you must not make a function call in the recursion. Here's how:

```
divTrials n = xs where xs = takeWhile (/=(1,1)) $ (2,n): map tryDiv xs
```

Just that change brings the time down to 7.85s. Still off by a factor of about 3, but much much better.

The less obvious problem lies here:

```
factorGroups = filter (not.null).map tail.group.map fst.divTrials
```

Putting the `group` so early breaks fusion, causing that intermediate list to actually be materialized. This means allocating and deallocating a lot of cons cells and tuples. Here's an implementation that has the same spirit, but puts more work before the `group`:

```
  tryDiv d n
    | n `mod` d == 0 = d : tryDiv d (n `div` d)
    | n == 1 = []
    | otherwise = tryDiv (d+1) n
  factorGroups = group . tryDiv 2
```

With that, we are down to 2.65s -- slightly faster than `ans2`, though I only did one test of each so it's pretty likely to just be measurement noise.

Comment: "Putting the group so early breaks fusion"
Why is that? They are all library functions (except the `\xs-> (head xs,length xs)` one). Any detail on inner workings of fusion that causes it?

Comment: If function calls are not memoized, am I right in saying that the next optimization I have in mind, namely, `| d<floor(sqrt n) = tryDiv (d+1) n` in `tryDiv`, causes `sqrt n` to be computed potentially several times for the same `n`?

Comment: @cobra Think a bit about what it would look like to fuse away `group` and you'll quickly see the answer to your question. (If you can't figure out what it would look like... well, then, you have your answer.)

Comment: @cobra Yes, don't do that. But the standard replacement is `| d*d < n` rather than trying to get clever about sharing `sqrt n` across several steps.